# PowerShell HTML Formatting

Tags: powershell

I am executing the below line of code and need to convert the Size Column from bytes to TB.

```
"<style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid;}</style>"
Get-PhysicalDisk -Manufacturer PureStorage | ConvertTo-Html -Property "FriendlyName", FirmwareVersion, PhysicalLocation, OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, Size -Head $Style | Out-File D:\Array.htm
```

Current output

[image]

Desire out put to display Size Column in TB.

Size/1024*1024*1024*1024 . Would like to round of to two decimal places.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Dough, that will work. How do I point my Column "Size" to that function so it does the conversion?

Comment: You can use this `Get-PhysicalDisk|select @{n='Size (TB)';e={[math]::Round($_.size/1tb,2)}}`. Add all the column names there too. You can also save `Get-PhysicalDisk` to a variable and cast a `PSCustomObject` out (I like this better).

Comment: Thanks Santiago,  the size column is not getting displayed. Did I miss anything?  ````Get-PhysicalDisk -Manufacturer PureStorage | ConvertTo-Html -Property FriendlyName, FirmwareVersion, PhysicalLocation, OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, select @{n='Size (TB)';e={[math]::Round($_.size/1tb,2)}} -Head $Style | Out-File D:\Array.htm````

Comment: Like this: `Get-PhysicalDisk -Manufacturer PureStorage | Select FriendlyName, FirmwareVersion, PhysicalLocation, OperationalStatus, HealthStatus, @{n='Size (TB)';e={[math]::Round($_.size/1tb,2)}} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-File D:\Array.htm`

Comment: Thank you Santiago, that worked.